# Why do XSS strings often start with ">?

Tags: xss

One of the ways, XSS can be exploited, is to use following tag:

```
"><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

Here, What is the meaning of `">` before script (`<script>` tag) and why it is used?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This way you escape from a double-quoted attribute (`"`) and close the previous tag (`>`) before opening a script tag that contains your payload. It's one of the most basic XSS patterns.

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="$XSS">
```

With your sequence it becomes:

```
<input type="text" value=""><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>">
 ^- a completed tag                  ^- payload           garbage -^
```

Note that your vector only works if HTML entities aren't filtered.

So if you can't escape from that attribute, it's XSS-safe. This doesn't trigger:

```
<input type="text" value="<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>">
```

You can see the same idea with XSS inside Javascript (e.g. `');` to end a string and a function call) or with SQL injections. The first characters of an injection sequence often have the purpose of escaping from the current context.

As for @Mindwin's obligatory [SQL injection xkcd strip](https://xkcd.com/327/), I freehand-circled the part I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: Mandatory XKCD: [#327: Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).